# How to insert value in SQLite table

Tags: ios, sqlite

This is code I'm using to insert data into table,

```
sqlite3 *database;

NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mobdb.sqlite"];
        if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)
        {   
            const char *sqlstatement = "INSERT INTO mobDetails (nMonId, nScore) VALUES (?,?)";
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledstatement;

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlstatement , -1, &compiledstatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSString * str1 =@"1";
                NSString * str2 =@"12";

                sqlite3_bind_int(compiledstatement, 1, [str1 integerValue]);
                sqlite3_bind_int(compiledstatement, 2, [str2 integerValue]);

                if(sqlite3_step(compiledstatement)==SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"done");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR");
                }
                sqlite3_reset(compiledstatement);
            }
            else
            {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error . '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
```

Its shows "done" message but data not inserted into the table can any one help me for this.

also how to insert string in the table ?

Comment: Try placing the mobdb.sqlite in the documents folder and then insert.

Comment: "How to insert value in sqlite table using xcode" - in no way. Xcode is not an SQLite editor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the app bundle is read-only (as you could have probably found out after 5 minutes of googling). Consequently, you can't insert to a database in the app bundle.

One thing that is wrong with the usage of the SQLite API is that you are calling `sqlite3_reset()` whereas `sqlite3_finalize()` should have been called. (Thanks @trojanfoe.)

<sub>(Oh, and this has **absolutely nothing** to do with Xcode at all.)</sub>

Comment: He still needs to use `finalize` instead of `reset`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Fair enough, I've amended my answer.

Comment: I tried with finalize even its not working

Comment: @Rajesh Again, because the DB is in the app bundle. Copy it to a writable location and **read carefully...**

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) saveData
{
     sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
     const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

     if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
           NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
             @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS 
             (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", 
             name.text, address.text, phone.text];
           const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
           sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, 
             -1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                 status.text = @"Contact added";
                 name.text = @"";
                 address.text = @"";
                 phone.text = @"";
            } else {
                  status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
```